# Strange Windows10 behaviour with iTunes and Powershell and ...?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, itunes

I am running Windows 10 on a desktop.  Nothing happened when I clicked the iTunes icon so I reinstalled it but this did not fix the problem.  There were also some network issues at the same time so I tried running PowerShell to PING the network.  The PowerShell window opened but there was no command prompt.  After leaving things as they were for a few days, I came back to the desktop to find that an iTunes window had appeared and the PowerShell command prompt was also working.  There is something odd going on with this machine but I have no idea what it could be, other than it might be related to accessing files on cloud drives (just a hunch).  Would appreciate any suggestions anyone might have

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to reboot it?

Comment: Yes - several times ...

Comment: Have you looked in the eventviewer for any problems? When did this occur? Have you tried restoring the computer to a point in time when everything worked ok? Have you installed new software since then? Malware at work? In short, besides rebooting have you tried **anything**?

Comment: The reason I am posting is because I have no idea what to try but thanks for your suggestions (a) there are no restore points (b) problem became noticeable early October and there have been a lot of software updates since but no new software (c) no malware according to malwarebytes (d) event viewer shows 43 DHCP errors (code 1001) in last 7 days - no other errors

Comment: No restore points.. hmmm. What you can try is to repair missing or corrupted system files. Open an elevated command prompt and run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`. When that finishes, type `sfc /scannow` to scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder "%WinDir%\System32\dllcache". Both actions take quite some time to finish. When done reboot your computer. P.S. If you want someone's attention in a comment, 'ping' this person by typing `@` followed by the persons name so he/she will be notified.

Comment: Hi @Theo - ran sfc and got this message "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations".  Wondering if this is a hardware issue?  BTW thanks for the "@" tip ...